# Parse a UTC date string to date in C#

Tags: c#, string, parsing, datetime

Simple question, I have this string:

```
string dateString = "7/12/2014 4:42:00 PM";
```

This is a date string and it's in the UTC timezone.

I need to convert it to a date, so I'm doing the following:

```
DateTimeOffset dateOffset;

DateTimeOffset.TryParse(dateString, out dateOffset);

DateTime date = dateOffset.UtcDateTime;
```

The problem:

When I'm parsing the string to date, the code is considering that the dateString is in the Local Timezone of the PC (+3 GMT), and not in the UTC timezone.

So I am getting the following the `dateOffset = {7/12/2014 4:42:00 PM +03:00}` and thus `date = {7/12/2014 1:42:00 PM}`

how can I tell him that the date string provided is in the UTC format and not in the local timezone format?

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> how can I tell him that the date string provided is in the UTC format and not in the local timezone format?

Specify a [`DateTimeStyles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91hfhz89(v=vs.110).aspx) value of `AssumeUniversal` in the call. That tells the parsing code what to do. For example:

```
// null here means the thread's current culture - adjust it accordingly.
if (DateTimeOffset.TryParse(dateString, null, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal,
                            out dateOffset))
{
    // Valid
}
```

You should always use the result of `TryParse` to tell whether or not it's successfully parsed.

If you know the format and the specific culture, I'd personally use `DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact`. (Well, to be honest I'd use my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) project to start with, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: Wow the great Jon Skeet answering my question. That's a bucket list entry done! Time to focus on my next entry: "Fly around the moon". Thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

There is another overload of [`DateTimeOffset.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397029(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
DateTimeOffset.TryParse Method (String, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles, DateTimeOffset)
```

which allows you specify [`DateTimeStyles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91hfhz89(v=vs.110).aspx). One of the `DateTimeStyles` is `AssumeUniversal`, which is what you're looking for:

> If no time zone is specified in the parsed string, the string is
>   assumed to denote a UTC. This value cannot be used with AssumeLocal or
>   RoundtripKind.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how .Net API provides, but I guess you could probably use [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format to indicate a UTC timezone before parsing, i.e, first translate `7/12/2014 4:42:00 PM` into something `2014-07-02T16:42:00Z`, then use try parse using DateTimeOffset